# Issue: FlatList rendering only few items in the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I am trying to render a list of 1500 items using a FlatList in react-native. But it is only displaying first 5 items. I am unable to scroll down to view the remaining data.

Below is the code implementation:

```
const renderItem = (item, index) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <View
        style={{
          borderWidth: 0.2,
          padding: 50,
          backgroundColor: index % 2 === 0 ? '#22c1c3' : '#5985f1',
        }}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '700'}}>{item.name} </Text>
        <View style={{marginTop: 10}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 14, fontWeight: '500'}}>Age:{item.age} </Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 14, fontWeight: '500'}}>
            Balance Amount:{item.balanceAmount}{' '}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const FooterComponent = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{height: 20,  width: '100%'}} />
  );
};

return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 25}}>
        <FlatList
          data={DATA}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => renderItem(item, index)}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
          initialNumToRender={10}
          windowSize={10}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          updateCellsBatchingPeriod={10}
          removeClippedSubviews
          ListFooterComponent={FooterComponent}
        />
      </View>
  );
```

The DATA is an array of 1500 objects in this format:

```
[
    {
      "id": "64f1c1df583fb14b25315553",
      "index": 0,
      "active": false,
      "balanceAmount": "$2,591.81",
      "age": 22,
      "name": "Fletcher Batcher"
    },
]
```

When there are interactions like state changes, there is an update in the list and all the data items are displayed properly.

I expect FlatList to display all the data properly without only displaying partial data.

React native version: 0.72.4

Comment: Try remove the prop `removeClippedSubviews` in Flatlist and try again, it is a feature full of bug. Also, try reducing the list item number to around 10 first to see whether the issue is about heavy workload in Flatlist or not.

Comment: My sample works as expected -> https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/large-flatlist